# What is a good way to quickly search through a defined range of email?

Tags: email, search, imap

For [an app I'm building](https://receiptrunner.com/) I need to search through a defined date range of a users emails with dozens of queries, preferably in a secure manner.

For Gmail this is easy enough, and the app already supports Gmail.

For IMAP, however, it's not. IMAP search seems super slow.

Would the best way be to download all email from the date range and make the search locally? E.g. basically keep a local copy around for x time, and use it for all search needs? If so, anyone got an opinion on the best way to search those emails?

Is there a way to search IMAP directly that won't run into speed issues?

I've dabbled with 3rd party solutions like [Nylas](https://www.nylas.com/) who promise an "API for email", but they seem to just pipe things to IMAP search and are just as slow.

Any hints or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say "IMAP", do you have particular server in mind?  There are literally dozens of common implementations, and some will search faster than others, or be entirely broken.  Caching locally can be fast, but very slow to begin with.  What kind of queries do you need to make?

Comment: IMAP searching is generally quite primitive. In general you should expect that some server may evaluate your search terms in the order you supply, for each message. Avoid redoing a search (if you've searched up to UID 12345 yesterday, start at 12346 today) and put the often-optimised search terms (UID, flags, header) before the body or text terms. Downloading and searching locally can work well on average, but the worst case is a user who has ten million messages. (One PDA mail client crashed on startup for me. It connected to the server, saw my mail, and had a heart attack.)

Comment: @arnt Very good tip about putting certain search terms first. I guess that means I should lead with SINCE and BEFORE as well, so it doesn't first search all email for the BODY part and then limit that search result after?

Comment: @Max I need to do searches that are probably one-time-only, so while I can cache them it won't help too much. The use case is to find receipts in email, and the searches might look something like a long list of OR-statements for different variety of one variable, constrained by a SINCE and BEFORE date range.

Typically a user will have to run hundreds of searches in parallell for the app to be useful, so if IMAP doesn't tackle that and will time out on me, then it might be better to load everything locally and run them on the client.

Comment: BTW, I found out that there's a HUGE difference between using SINCE/BEFORE and SENTSINCE/SENTBEFORE to limit date ranges. The latter performs 2-3 orders of magnitude worse (minutes vs single digit seconds)

Comment: @arnt Do you think the server will start with the oldest messages first, or the newest messages first when evaluating?

Comment: If you want hundreds of searches, I think you might want to run one (or a few) server searches to identify candidates and weed out most of the irrelevant messages, download the candidates, and do the hundreds on the client. That way you won't blow up when you come across someone with millions of irrelevant messages. You could also use OR OR OR to construct a single very large search, but I've heard about servers that couldn't even handle 50 search terms...

Comment: The server reports all matches at once at the end of executing the search, so clients don't have much insight into how it's done.